# How To Parse A Website?

Tags: iphone, mobile, screen-scraping, ipod-touch

Hey I would like to build an app that could parse a website in order to get specific information. Specifically something that can parse http://www.fedex.com/Tracking?language=english&cntry_code=us&tracknumbers=681780934297262 for the important information. Is there a tutorial out there I could use.

Comment: The universal consensus on StackOverflow is that regular expressions are the best solution for parsing HTML. Unless you are Jon Skeet. He can't seem to do it.

Comment: Except for Python developers, who avoid regular expressions (because they don't work in general for HTML) and use the Beautiful Soup package.

Answer (score 2):

This [Cocoa With Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html) article discusses parsing XML and HTML with the `libxml2` library that is available with Xcode, using [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) to pull out the node(s) of interest. Take a look at the `PerformHTMLXPathQuery()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this tool: http://code.google.com/p/sitescraper/